# How to get MP3 file into iPad Music app without iTunes?

Tags: ipad, windows, mp3

Background: My Mac is out of commission, I don't want to borrow my son's Windows 8 laptop, and I don't want to install iTunes (or anything else that touches the Registry) on my employer's Window 7.

I have an MP3 file that I edited with "portable audacity" and I want to use "Music" with it.  I know there are other programs that can play it, but I have my reasons...

I've heard there are other programs that can get MP3s into the Music library.  Are any of them Windows-portable, i.e., can run from a flash drive without adding more garbage into the already full garbage can called "Registry"?

Or is there a portable file manager (for Windows) that can replace an MP3 file **in the Music library** with another of the same name (without jailbreaking to tamper with permissions)?  (In other words, something that would do what iTunes can do but won't touch the Windows registry.)

bmike, the answer is "if you think it's clearer, go for it."  SE is not cooperating with letting me log in and comment at the moment.  And I'll have my Mac again soon, at which point the question is only of value to someone besides me.  :-)

Comment: Searching for this is challenging. I've linked this to an earlier question asking the same idea. On Mac OS X, I use PhoneView to place music (and other) files on the iPad without needing iTunes.

Comment: That is a similar question, but not exactly a duplicate.  I WANT to use the app formerly known as iTunes on the iPad, but at the moment, I don’t have access to it on Mac or Windows.  So far, all the answers I’ve seen here or elsewhere either say it can’t be done, or they tell me how to do something else.  The other question has only two answers, and they aren't answers to how to get them **into the Music apps library** when iTunes on a computer is not available.

Comment: How about I take a stab at editing it to ask for portable version of iTunes or substitute? Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but all the Programs i know out there which are really able to add Files to the coorrect place (iTunes Folder on your iPod) will ask you to first install iTunes to use its sync Function in the Background.

Comment: Someone told me this weekend that "floola" could do it.  I just looked at its website.  FAQ tells how to "repair" the music DB if Floola corrupts it.  Sounds like a tool I don't want to risk.

Comment: Took the chance, but it couldn't find the iPad--and said "touches and iphones not supported"

Answer (score 0):

You could email it to whatever email account is set up on the iPad. That at least gets it on the device, if not into the actual Music app.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer is, “No.”

Searching other places had the same lack of results.